# Working on a Django project. Restrict API access based on the user's group permissions

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a custom user model with group as a field.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
class Users(AbstractBaseUser): 
    group=models.ManyToManyField(Group, blank=True)
```

I'm assigning model permissions to the group from Django admin panel.
Now I want to make sure that the user's group permission should be checked before a user can access an API like this:

```
@authentication_classes([TokenAuthentication])
class SiteList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, GroupPermission] //GroupPermission as a check
    queryset = Site.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SiteSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making a custom Permission for this view.

Example that check if user has "Customer" group:

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class GroupPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if "Customer" in request.user.group.values_list("name", flat=True):
            return True
        return False
```

Then add it to permission_classes variable.

If you want to check exact permission that group should have, then you can make this check:

```
if Permission.objects.filter(Q(user=request.user) | Q(group__user=request.user), codename="can_do_something").exists()
```

More info here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/